# ActiveRecord: Search multiple models for a list of words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a search controller where I want to search a number of different models.

So say I have this query: "Foo bar baz". Then I want to have the following queries:

```
Model1.where("name like '%foo%' or name like '%bar%' or name like '%baz'").offset(o).limit(l)
Model2.where("title like '%foo%' or title like '%bar%' or title like '%baz'").offset(o).limit(l)
Model3.joins(:sources).where("sources.name" => [source1, source2]).where("name like '%foo%' or name like '%bar%' or name like '%baz'").offset(o).limit(l)
```

Most important is that I want to do it safe (no SQL injections) but it would be nice if I could keep it DRY and pretty as well. I am using Rails 4 but I am very new to it. I have seen that there's something called "Concerns" which may be something to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Dependencies**

You'll probably be best using one of the search extensions for Ruby stacks:

> - [Sunspot Solr](http://sunspot.github.io/)
> - [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)
> - [Sphynx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)

As a disclaimer, I've never used any of these in production, but from my understanding, each of them will "index" data in your application, and then perform a search based on that indexed data

--

**Indexing**

The bottom line is if you want to search multiple models, you'll be best harnessing an index-based search system. This will take all the data you want to index, and put it into a manageable, searchable format that you can then call when you need.

As far as I know, sunspot works very well in this regard (indexing your data). The trick is to include all your models in the Sunspot settings, from which you can then pull the data you need.

There's a great Railscast about this [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot):

[image]

I don't have any live code for you I'm afraid  - if you need more ideas, though, I'll gladly come back with them